# Как скрыть индексы в NpArray?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

Имеется следующий код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


lst_b = [['AAAAAAAAAA', 2022, '11112222', 50.0, 112, 1, 'ABABAB'], ['BBBBBBBBBB', 2023, '33334444', 77.2, 115, 1, 'CDCDCD']]

lst_b = np.array(lst_b)

reshaped = lst_b.reshape(-1, 7)
pd.options.display.width = None

print(1.0, pd.DataFrame(reshaped, columns=['Name', 'YEAR', 'ID', 'VALUE', 'TYPE', 'STATUS', 'CODE']))
```

Который выводит такую таблицу:

```
         Name  YEAR        ID VALUE TYPE STATUS    CODE
0  AAAAAAAAAA  2022  11112222  50.0  112      1  ABABAB
1  BBBBBBBBBB  2023  33334444  77.2  115      1  CDCDCD
```

Вопрос состоит в том, чтобы скрыть отображения колонки с индексами. То есть, чтоб получилась такая таблица:

```
      Name  YEAR        ID VALUE TYPE STATUS    CODE
AAAAAAAAAA  2022  11112222  50.0  112      1  ABABAB
BBBBBBBBBB  2023  33334444  77.2  115      1  CDCDCD
```

Возможно ли такое вообще?
Пробовал различные `index = False`, `.hide()` и пр., но всегда выдает ошибку, что такие методы отсутствуют у объектов NpArray.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(...)  print(df.to_string(index=False))

Comment: Спасибо.
По ходу, мне всё ломала координата '1.0' в принте - скопировал ее с функции вывода в TKinter, где она обязательна.